# How do I get neo4j cyhper to return the top of a tree

Tags: tree, neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j graph that implements a tree structure (like folders of folders).  Is there any easy cypher query that will return the top of the tree.

Example,

```
(f2)-[CONTAINS]->(f3)

(f1)-[CONTAINS]->(f2)

(f3)-[CONTAINS]->(f4)
```

what query will return `(f1)`?

Answer (score 2):

Cypher has the ability to match variable length paths.

```
MATCH path=(f4)<-[:CONTAINS*1..5]-(top) 
RETURN top 
ORDER BY length(path) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This query will match all paths of length 1-5 and return the node furthest away from f4.

Comment: Thanks for this. On reflection I think my question was badly phrased.  I really want a cypher query that returns nodes that have _no_ incoming **CONTAINS** relationship.

Comment: Something like this: `MATCH (n) WHERE NOT (n)<-[:CONTAINS]-() RETURN n`?